# Capturing hostname & data when executing local script on remote server

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, perl

While trying to execute a local script on remotely host unable to get hostname of the remoteserver to a local output file.

For example I am executing a script below.

```
ssh remotehost sh -s < sudo su - ; ./localscript --include Yes > output
```

Above is working fine. below is an example output

```
script executed data from the remote machine
```

But I need the hostname + data like this.

```
remotehost: script executed data from the remote machine
```

For I tried using awk and it failed, can someone check this & help.

```
ssh remotehost sh -s < sudo su - ; ./localscript --include Yes | awk -vhostname=$(hostname) '{print hostname, $0}' > output
```

This is giving me localhost hostname. Please correct me if I am doing this wrong.
Also sorry if I am not explaining this properly put a comment I will modify & correct it.

I tried this and its wotking, but unable to do "grep" / "awk" output

```
ssh remotehost sh -s < `./localscript --include Yes` 

ssh remotehost sh -s < `./localscript --include Yes | awk -vhostname=$(hostname) '{print hostname, $0}' > output`
```

Comment: `sh -s < sudo su - ; ./localscript ...` isn't going to work. Ever.  and everything after the `;` will be executed as a separate command on the local host, not the remote host.    use `sudo ./localscript ...`.    If you want the pipe to awk to happen on the remote host, you need to quote the entire command line.  Maybe use a heredoc (`<<EOF...EOF` or <<<"$var") to simplify and avoid most quoting issues.

Comment: If I remove ";" its getting hung or not exiting from client server, not getting executed, Also i check sudo is also not required. its already acess the client host via root.

Comment: @cas please check update

Comment: `ssh remotehost sh -s < sudo su - ; ./localscript --include Yes > output` sends the content of a file called `sudo`, found in your local directory, to a remote shell. It then runs `localscript`, also in your correct directory, locally, sending its output to the file `output`

Comment: @roaima I got that, but I have removed "sudo su - ;" as its not required. Currently I am using ```ssh remotehost sh -s < `./localscript --include Yes` > output```. But as I am not getting hostname output, so unable to verify if its gettign exeuted properly on remote host or not

Comment: also I am getting this error ```-bash: ./localscript --include Yes` > output: ambiguous redirect```

Comment: output file is empty

Comment: Please put that into your question, replacing the wrong information that's currently there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the output saved to a file called "output" on the **local** host:

```
scp -p ./localscript remotehost:
ssh -q remotehost <<'EOF' > output
./localscript --include Yes |
   awk -vhostname=$(hostname) '{print hostname, $0}'
EOF
```

The `-q` option for ssh is used to suppress the warning message saying "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal." - this is necessary because stdin is redirected from the heredoc.

This uses what is called a "Here Document" or "heredoc" to provide input to `ssh`.   The word `EOF` is just an arbitrary word, with no special meaning in itself - but it's commonly used with heredocs because it stands for "End Of File" (`EOT` is also often used, for "End Of Text"). Any word that isn't on a line by itself in the text you want to redirect can be used.

Everything from the next line following that word (EOF) to the next occurrence of it (on a line by itself) is treated as input to the `ssh` command, and executed on the remote host.

The quotes around the word `EOF` makes it so that the entire heredoc is effectively inside a single-quoted string.  From `man bash` (search for "Here Documents"):

> Here Documents
>
> This type of redirection instructs the shell to  read  input  from  the
> current source until a line containing only delimiter (with no trailing
> blanks) is seen.  All of the lines read up to that point are then  used
> as  the  standard  input (or file descriptor n if n is specified) for a
> command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
> [n]<<[-]word
>         here-document
> delimiter
> ```
>
> No parameter and variable expansion, command  substitution,  arithmetic
> expansion,  or pathname expansion is performed on word.
>
> If any part of
> word is quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal  on  word,
> and  the  lines  in the here-document are not expanded.
>
> If word is
> unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to  parameter
> expansion,  command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character
> sequence <newline is ignored, and \ must be used to quote the characters
> , $, and `.

If you want the output saved to a file called output on the **remote** host:

```
scp -p ./localscript remotehost:
ssh -q remotehost <<'EOF'
./localscript --include Yes |
   awk -vhostname=$(hostname) '{print hostname, $0}' > output
EOF
```

Take notice of where the `> output` redirection is located in both versions: immediately after the `<<'EOF'` for the first version, and after the `awk` for the second.

---

It seems, though, that what you're really trying to do is re-invent a very basic version of existing tools like [Parallel Distributed Shell (pdsh)](https://github.com/chaos/pdsh).

I very strongly recommend you use `pdsh` (or one of several similar programs) instead of re-inventing it.   It should be available packaged for most distributions (definitely available for debian, ubuntu, etc).

e.g. on my home network, I have four machines (ganesh, indra, kali, and hex - i got bored with the naming scheme for the last machine and went for Discworld instead of Hindu gods).  I've configured pdsh to know that these hosts are in group "all", so I can run things like:

```
$ pdsh -g all 'uptime; uname -a'
hex:  18:35:00 up 45 days, 21:07,  1 user,  load average: 0.33, 0.41, 0.43
hex: Linux hex 5.10.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.19-1 (2021-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
kali:  18:35:00 up 20:40,  2 users,  load average: 1.46, 0.92, 0.68
kali: Linux kali 5.10.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.28-1 (2021-04-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
ganesh:  18:35:00 up 45 days, 21:23, 22 users,  load average: 1.34, 1.67, 1.85
ganesh: Linux ganesh 5.10.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.19-1 (2021-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
indra:  18:35:00 up 5 days, 19:51,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.03, 0.02
indra: Linux indra 5.10.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.28-1 (2021-04-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Notice that it already does what you're trying to do with the `awk` command - prefix the output with the remote machine's hostname.

Also Note: the order of output isn't guaranteed to be nicely grouped like that.  `pdsh` runs multiple ssh connections in parallel, and the remote machines will take their own sweet time responding.  You can, of course, pipe the output to `sort -k1,1`.

`pdsh` includes a utility called `pdcp` to copy files to remote hosts.  e.g. if i wanted to copy `./localscript` to all of my machines and run it on them, I'd run:

```
pdcp -p -g all ./localscript '~/'
pdsh -g all ./localscript
```

BTW, `pdsh` also comes with a nice utility called `dshbak` which can re-format the output, grouping it by the host it came from.

```
$ pdsh -g all 'uptime; uname -a' | dshbak 
----------------
kali
----------------
 18:35:12 up 20:41,  2 users,  load average: 1.51, 0.96, 0.70
Linux kali 5.10.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.28-1 (2021-04-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
----------------
indra
----------------
 18:35:12 up 5 days, 19:51,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.03, 0.02
Linux indra 5.10.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.28-1 (2021-04-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
----------------
ganesh
----------------
 18:35:12 up 45 days, 21:23, 22 users,  load average: 1.52, 1.70, 1.86
Linux ganesh 5.10.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.19-1 (2021-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
----------------
hex
----------------
 18:35:12 up 45 days, 21:07,  1 user,  load average: 0.26, 0.39, 0.42
Linux hex 5.10.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.19-1 (2021-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: upon executing both type of method, getting this error ```Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
-bash: line 1: ./localscript: No such file or directory```

Comment: @Mongrel 1. Use `ssh -q` to suppress warning messages.   2.  You know where your `localscript` is - I have no idea, I just used the path you specified.  If it's not where you said it was, fix your question.

Comment: More importantly: install and configure pdsh, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: ```./localscript``` file is on the local machine /root/localscript, which should get executed on remote server and collect the output to the local mcahine from where the script got executed.

Comment: If it's only on the local machine, it **can't** be executed on the remote host - it isn't there to be executed.  How would you expect it to run there if the remote machine doesn't have a copy?    If you need it there, use `scp -p` to copy it there before trying to execute it.